# How to install EB CLI on Windows?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have used the entire day trying to install EB CLI on windows in order to connect to AWS Elastic Beanstalk but I keep getting the same error:

```
Running setup.py install for docker-py
Could not find .egg-info directory in install record for docker-py>=1.1.0 <=1.7.2 (from awsebcli)
```

I started out with the latest version of Python but after reading of other users issues on Stack Overflow I decided to downgrade my Python version to 3.4.0. However, I still get the same error, meaning that I cannot do EB init to connect to my Elastic Beanstalk instance since it does not recognise the command.

I also tried to un-install docker-py and re-install it - still not working.

Any ideas to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if you may have version conflicts. See a [similar issue here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4569)

Try installing `awsebcli` in a virtual environment, as suggested by the [aws docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-virtualenv.html).